# How to switch between two ViewControllers combined with a NavigationController in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

this is my storyboard:

[image]

I would like to switch automatically from my ScanTable (TableViewController) back to my StartPage in some specific cases. So I added the following code, to switch between the both Views:

```
let startPage:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StartPage")
self.presentViewController(startPage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So this code works, but there are two issues:

1. The StartPage doesn't contain a Navigation bar. Is there any possibility to reset the Navigation Controller or something like that to get my Navigation bar on the top back?
2. The animation from my ScanTable to my StartPage is different to any other swap animation. Can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewController, animated: true)
```

to go to the yourViewController you wanted to show.

or

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

if you need to go back to your first VC.

Comment: Nice, it works! But there is one little bug with the animation. The background color of the navigation bar refreshes irregular... So it fills a little bit, stops and fills the rest. Can I solve this behavior?

Comment: I have found a work around. If I disable the translucent button for the  navigation bar, it looks pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

You can set some properties on appdelegate file.

An example:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
```